# Best practice for grouping Java classes for instantiation clarity

Tags: java, inner-classes, organization

I am building a piece of software that sends and receives messages in particular binary definitions and with a particular version. As such, I have classes that look like this, which vary mostly only in the package name (the version, in this case):

For version 1.5:

```
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0105.fielddefinitions.Field100
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0105.fielddefinitions.Field200
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0105.messagedefinitions.Pants
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0105.messagedefinitions.Socks
```

and for version 2.7:

```
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.fielddefinitions.Field100
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.fielddefinitions.Field200
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.messagedefinitions.Pants
com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.messagedefinitions.Socks
```

The class that manages the transmission and reception of these messages uses all versions, depending on where the message comes from, etc.

My problem is that defining an instance of the class requires I use the entire package path, because otherwise it's ambiguous. Even if there exists a situation where I use only one version in a given file, a casual reader of the code won't be able to see what version is being used. `Pants pants = new Pants()` is ambiguous until you look at the imported package.

My ideal usage of this would be something like this:

```
V0207.Pants pantsMessage = new V0702.Pants();
```

That makes it very clear what version is being used. I could make this happen by creating the Pants message classes as inner classes of the V0207 class, but then the V0207 class becomes gigantic (there could be a hundred messages, each with 100 fields, for every given version). Is there possibly a way to #include an inner class, so they can be stored in separate files? This would be ideal.

I suppose I can emulate this with a wrapper class, that does something (silly?) like this, where there exists an instance of the Pants class in the V0207 object:

```
Object pantsMessage = V0207.pants.getClass().newInstance();
((com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.messagedefinitions.Pants)pantsMessage).getZipperType();
```

But I dislike that. It looks contrived and requires try/catch and casting when in use. Terrible.

I could also use a factory. That would be a bit nicer, but requires a parent class (or interface) and would require casting when used, since each message has unique methods.

```
Message pantsMessage = V0207Factory.newMessage(V0207.PantsMessage);
((com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.messagedefinitions.Pants)pantsMessage).getZipperType();
```

or

```
Message sockMessage = V0207Factory.newSock();
((com.mydomain.clothesmessage.v0207.messagedefinitions.Socks)sockMessage).getSmellLevel();
```

What are your thoughts? I'm using JDK 1.7, but 1.8 might be usable.

Comment: Put the version number in the constructor Javadoc of your classes.  That way, when you mouse over the constructor, the comment will show the version number.  If you need the version number for every method, you might be able to create a pre-compile process that puts the version number on every method Javadoc.

Comment: Yes, certainly the Javadoc of the constructor and class will contain the version. But that does require an IDE and the action to bring up the Javadoc. Also, that addresses only a small part of the problem. I'd really like to not have to specify the entire package path when instancing the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially solved this by using inner static classes in one gigantic "version" class. Thus, the use looked like this:

```
V0207.Pants pantsMessage = new V0702.Pants();
```

But the version class ('V0207') grew too quickly, especially as other developers on the team demanded a more "Java" way of setting the fields (which required a lot of getters and setters).

Thus, the final solution is to put the messages inside their own v0207.messages package name, and prepend each message with the version:

```
V0207_Pants pantsMessage = new V0702_Pants();
```

It's not as nice as using a C++ namespace, but it works. The version is clear to the reader, and the object can contain a lot of code without any files becoming too large.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the factory design pattern with interfaces.  The version of Java that you use does not make a difference (though support for Java 7 goes away in the spring, April if I remember correctly).

Define an interface for each class containing the method signatures that will be implemented by all the versions of the class.

Update your class definitions to include the appropriate interface definition.

Create a class factory for each needed class, passing it the information needed to create the appropriate version of the class.  This class factory should return the interface type for the created class.

Here is an example:

**TestPants**

```
public class TestPants {
    IPants pants = PantsFactory.PantsFactory(207);
    Message zipperType = pants.getZipperType();
    Message color = pants.getColor();
    )
}
```

**IPants**

```
public interface IPants {
    Message getZipperType();
    Message getColor();
}
```

**Pants**

```
public class Pants implements IPants {
    // Class fields and Object fields
    @Override
    public Message getColor () {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public Message getZipperType () {
        return null;
    }
    // implement any common methods among all versions
}
```

**PantsV0105**

```
public class PantsV0105 extends Pants {
    // add changes for this version
}
```

**PantsV0207**

```
public class PantsV0207 extends Pants {
    // add changes for this version
}
```

**PantsFactory**

```
public class PantsFactory {
    public static IPants PantsFactory(int version) {
        switch (version) {
        case 105: return new PantsV0105(); break;
        case 207: return new PantsV0207(); break;
            default: return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I knew there was something I was forgetting. I didn't want to use a Factory, because it requires a parent class. I'll update my question.

Comment: Use an Interface in conjunction with the class factory

Comment: After your edit: I don't know what you mean about using an `Interface`. I think an interface at the level of the message wouldn't be very useful. It would only specify the version, right? The version can be derived by the package path anyway. As long as we're using an IDE to reference documentation, an `Interface` or "just-read-the-package-path" are pretty much equal. Or am I missing something? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Interface and factory is the pattern you need.  Can you provide some of the methods that you want to use for one of your example classes .. I can then provide a small working example.

Comment: The methods can be anything, I just need a reference. Say, Pants.showMap() and Pants.getDescription().

Comment: After edit with examples: Right, that's a typical Factory pattern. But that doesn't address my concerns. 1) It still requires that I cast the returned object using the full package path, if I want to use a method/field that doesn't exist in the interface or parent class (this will happen a lot). 2) It requires (at minimum) a single parent class or interface (or both!) for every single message object in the entire system!

Comment: Looks like the real problem may be in the object design for your problem (no insult intended).  Perhaps refactoring the classes makes more sense (we may need more of a description of that).  Do you have products, messages and what other sort of objects that make up the intellectual framework of your application?

Comment: You may be right, but I can't see how to improve it. These objects are defined by a message standard. A Standard has Messages, Messages have Fields, Fields have a binary and <Type> value. This is an (almost) perfect use of nested classes, except that the file size gets huge and (minor point) static fields aren't allowed. I want to type `Standard.Message message = new Standard.Message()`, and have access to all the (public) `Message.Field`s that exist within a given message. But maybe I need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68152/discussion-between-erstwhileiii-and-jmbeck).